# how to send link name to action class

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts2, struts

In Struts2 by using link tag I want to send a value associated with the link clicked to the action class, consider a menu if I am clicking on a particular menu name then that name should be send to the action class. Currently I am using.

```
<a href="<s:url action="JanuaryAction"/>">January</a>
```

How do I add a name to it, when I click on this January, I should be able to get some data in action class. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use script to do this:

```
function setActionval(val)
{
   document.getElementById("action").value=val;
}
```

And you have to use the link as

```
<a href="javascript:setActionval('January')">January</a>
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: What is element with `action` id?

Comment: I clicked this as an answer not because this was appropriate, it just gave me another way to look into my problem. anyway the first answer is not that helpful anyway i got answer by myself.thanks for your effort..

Comment: <s:url action="JanuaryAction.action" var="urlTag" >
    <s:param name="name">January 2013</s:param>
</s:url>
<a href="<s:property value="#urlTag" />" >January 2013</a><br><br><br>

Comment: @user2482323: You should really approve answer that answers your question which is DaveHowes one, not the answer that makes zero sense.

Comment: no, i tried that answer, but didnt workout, then i tried my own, it worked out

Comment: I dont know for no reason why my question was marked down.? please answer

Comment: Maybe because you haven't looked at the docs before posting it and accepted wrong answer. @DaveHowes gave the correct answer and yours answer is simple copy of his.

Comment: How can you say its copy, i have used property tag in it, whereas in his answer, you can not see that so it doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

You can add URL parameters which will be available to your action as follows :

```
<s:url action="JanuaryAction" >
    <s:param name="name">January</s:param>
</s:url>
```

This would add the url parameter "name" with a value of "January" to the request that gets submitted to the JanuaryAction when you click this link